# Is it possible to return part of a field from the last row entered into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am proposing to have a table (the design isn't settled on yet and can be altered dependent upon the views expressed in reply to this question) that will have a primary key of type int (using auto increment) and a field (ReturnPeriod of type Nchar) that will contain data in the form of '06 2013'  (representing in this instance June 2013).

I would simply like to return 06  or whatever happens to be in the last record entered in the table. This table will never grow by more than 4 records per annum (so it will never be that big).  It also has a column indicating the date that the last entry was created.

That column seems to my mind at least to be the most suitable candidate for getting the last record, so essentially I'd like to know if sql has a inbuilt function for comparing the date the query is run to the nearest match in a column, and to return the first two characters of a field.

So far I have:

```
Select Mid(ReturnPeriod,1,2) from Returns
Where DateReturnEntered = <and this is where I'm stuck>
```

What I'm looking for is a where clause that would get me the last entered record using the date the query is run as its reference point(DateRetunEntered of type Date contains the date a record was entered).

Of course there may be an even easier way to guarantee that one has the last record in which case I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store `ReturnPeriod` as a datetime for example not `06 2013` as a VARCHAR but `01.06.2013` as a DATETIME (first day of 06.2013).

In this case, if I've got your question right, you can use [GETDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) to get current time:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MONTH(ReturnPeriod) 
 FROM Returns 
 WHERE DateReturnEntered<=GETDATE()
 ORDER BY DateReturnEntered DESC
```

If you store `ReturnPeriod` as a `varchar` then

```
SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(ReturnPeriod,2)
 FROM Returns 
 WHERE DateReturnEntered<=GETDATE()
 ORDER BY DateReturnEntered DESC
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer.  The whole table is being used to store VAT returns and the return date (because the tax is done on a quarterly basis is always in the form of '06 2013' or whatever thae relevant period is.  I agree that having a datetime type for the column would make life easier, but in doing so you loose the actual reference that one is after.

Comment: Just played with your second suggestion which seems to do the job very nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would store your `ReturnPeriod` as a `date` datatype, using a nominal 1st of the month, e.g. 1 Jun 2013, if you don't have the actual date.

This will allow direct comparison against your entered date, with trivial formatting of the return value if required.

Your query would then find the latest date prior to your date entered.

```
SELECT MONTH(MAX(ReturnPeriod)) AS ReturnMonth
FROM Returns
WHERE ReturnPeriod <= @DateReturnEntered
```